# how to identify or group uploaded files of same submit request on server side

Tags: fine-uploader

With [fine-uploader](http://fineuploader.com) js library, is there built-in mechanism to set some uniqe identification for form, i.e. all uploaded files will have the same parameter-value to make possible group them on server-side.

Or I have to generate, say some uuid for my self ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [form support feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/forms.html), simply include an ID form field of your choosing, and it will be sent with all files. Another option is to call the [`setParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams), passing a ID that describes the group of files to be uploaded. A third option involves registering an [`onAllComplete` event handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#allComplete), where you can send a request to your server with information about all of the uploaded files. You can use the [`getUploads` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUploads) to obtain this information.

Comment: Using the "form support feature" works perfect for me: all uploaded files are now properly stored in a subfolder with the name of the uploader ($_REQUEST['user_name']). I'm using the "php-traditional-server" as a backend.

Just one thing I cant get to work now is: deleting the uploaded file. Since the path changed, the request "DELETE http://host/traditional-server/endpoint.php/<uuid>" is not sufficient. Furthermore the $_REQUEST['user_name'] is empty so I can't get the information from there.

Now the question is: how can I change the link for deletion to include the "user_name" value?